# WebApi. Bicep created ConnectionString does not work

Tags: c#, azure-web-app-service, azure-bicep

I have a web api that i publish to an app service (linux app service plan) in azure.
I'm getting the error "System.InvalidOperationException The ConnectionString property has not been initialized." when trying to get data from my database.
I have concluded the problem is reading the connection string from the azure configuration.

I'm running .Net 7. My app service stack is sat to .net and .net 7 as version. My app service is connected to a linux app service plan.
I have an Azure Devops release pipeline that pushes my code. The first task in an Azure CLI that runs my Bicep. The next task is an Deploy Azure App Service.

My bicep section for connection string is

```
secure()
param DBConectionString string = ''
   
resource connectionstrings 'Microsoft.Web/sites/config@2022-03-01' = {
name: 'connectionstrings'
kind: 'string'
parent: api
properties:  {
   DBConectionString: {
      value: DBConectionString
      type:'PostgreSQL'
   }
  }
}
```

Based upon the documentation from Microsoft this should be correct.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.web/sites/config-connectionstrings?pivots=deployment-language-bicep

It deploys without a problem.
[image: Azure configuration Connection strings]

Problem is getting the connectionstring in my C# code.
I created a test method in on one of my controllers to test reading the connection string.
Just for testing I verifyed that my app could read config variable
Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("someVariable")
This test is successfull.
Getting connectionstring using

```
IConfiguration.GetConnectionString("DBConectionString")
```

returns string.Empty.

Getting connectionstring using

```
Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("connectionstrings:DBConectionString") ?? string.Empty;
```

returns string.Empty

Getting connectionstring using

```
Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("POSTGRESQLCONNSTR_DBConectionString") ?? string.Empty;
```

returns the connection string.

I have also tried to change the name parameter in my Bicep code to

```
secure()
param DBConectionString string = ''
   
resource connectionstrings 'Microsoft.Web/sites/config@2022-03-01' = {
name: 'ConnectionStrings'
kind: 'string'
parent: api
properties:  {
   DBConectionString: {
      value: DBConectionString
      type:'PostgreSQL'
   }
  }
}
```

That causes an error in my release pipeline.

To get around this I added a new app setting with my connection string as value(key vault ref). This works fine.

Comment: is it net6 / net7 ? have you tried setting that as an app settings ?

Comment: This is net7. The web app is set to stack .net and version .net 7. The app service is connected to a linux app service plan

Comment: Thanks for the infos. Have you tried the appsettings approach

Comment: Yes I have. Using just app settings works fine and it's a god work around. But we are suposed to use the ConnectionStrings section aren't we. Curious why that doesn't work.

Comment: Tbh I think the connectionstring section was introduced a while ago cause web.config was using that and pp service was windows only. I dont think it matter anymore